# Execute XSLT Transform from Java with parameter

Tags: java, xslt

I am executing an XSLT transform from within my java web application with no problems, as follows:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xslSource);
transformer.transform(xmlInput, xmlOutput);
```

In my XSLT transform I am now adding a call to the `document()` function to load the response from a RESTful web service:

```
<!-- do stuff -->
<xsl:variable name="url">
   http://server/service?id=<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:call-template name="doMoreStuff">
   <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="document($url)/foo"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Ok cool, no problem. But now, I want to read the base URL from a utils class in java and pass it in to the stylesheet.

```
//java
String baseUrl = myUtils.getBaseUrl();

<!-- xslt -->
<xsl:variable name="url">
   <xsl:value-of select="$baseUrl"/>
   <xsl:text>/service?id=</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Any suggestion on how to do this? My Java utils class loads the value from a myApp.properties file on the classpath, but I'm not sure I can utilize that from XSLT...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare an [`xsl:param`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#variables) in your stylesheet, so that the `baseUrl` value can be passed at invocation time:

```
<xsl:param name="baseUrl" />
```

Set the parameter on the `Transformer` object:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xslSource);
transformer.setParameter('baseUrl', myUtils.getBaseUrl());
transformer.transform(xmlInput, xmlOutput);
```

**If you are using XSLT 2.0, then you may consider using the [`resolve-uri()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-resolve-uri) function when you are constructing the `url` variable value:**

```
<xsl:variable name="url" 
              select="resolve-uri(concat('/service?id=', @id), $baseUrl)" />
```

**[resolve-uri()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-resolve-uri)** can help compensate for trailing slashes, hashtags, and other things in the `baseUrl` that might otherwise result an invalid URL to be constructed by simply concatenating the `$baseUrl` with the fragment and `@id`.

Comment: Important to note that `<xsl:param>` must be declared at the top level of the stylesheet. If you declare it within a template, it will be considered a parameter to the template not to the whole stylesheet.

Answer (score 6):

Call `setParameter` on your Transformer instance, with the name and value of your parameter. Then inside your XSLT document declare the parameter using `<xsl:param name="yourParamName" />` and you can then use it in your XSLT for example this way: `<xsl:value-of select="$yourParamName" />`