# XSLT copy elements with condition

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

at first I would like to know if this is even possible using xslt and if so how to do that:

I have two xmls.
The first one is holding informations about invoices

```
<INVOICES>
    <INVOICE>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>FV2014000572</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <SUPPLIER_NAME>Supplier 1</SUPPLIER_NAME>
    </INVOICE>
    <INVOICE>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>FV2014000573</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <SUPPLIER_NAME>Supplier 1</SUPPLIER_NAME>
    </INVOICE>
</INVOICES>
```

and second is holding concrete informations about invoice items

```
<INVOICE_ITEMS>
    <INVOICE_ITEM>
        <ITEM_INVOICE_NUMBER>FV2014000572</ITEM_INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <ITEM_NAME>ITEM 1</ITEM_NAME>
    </INVOICE_ITEM>
    <INVOICE_ITEM>
        <ITEM_INVOICE_NUMBER>FV2014000573</ITEM_INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <ITEM_NAME>ITEM 1</ITEM_NAME>
    </INVOICE_ITEM>
    <INVOICE_ITEM>
        <ITEM_INVOICE_NUMBER>FV2014000573</ITEM_INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <ITEM_NAME>ITEM 2</ITEM_NAME>
    </INVOICE_ITEM>
<INVOICE_ITEMS>
```

I'd like to transform this two xmls to one in following format:

```
<INVOICES>
    <INVOICE>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>FV2014000572</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <SUPPLIER_NAME>Supplier 1</SUPPLIER_NAME>
        <INVOICE_ITEMS>
            <INVOICE_ITEM>
                <ITEM_INVOICE_NUMBER>FV2014000572</ITEM_INVOICE_NUMBER>
                <ITEM_NAME>ITEM 1</ITEM_NAME>
            </INVOICE_ITEM>
        </INVOICE_ITEMS>
    </INVOICE>
    <INVOICE>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>FV2014000573</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <SUPPLIER_NAME>Supplier 1</SUPPLIER_NAME>
        <INVOICE_ITEMS>
            <INVOICE_ITEM>
                <ITEM_INVOICE_NUMBER>FV2014000573</ITEM_INVOICE_NUMBER>
                <ITEM_NAME>ITEM 1</ITEM_NAME>
            </INVOICE_ITEM>
            <INVOICE_ITEM>
                <ITEM_INVOICE_NUMBER>FV2014000573</ITEM_INVOICE_NUMBER>
                <ITEM_NAME>ITEM 2</ITEM_NAME>
            </INVOICE_ITEM>
        </INVOICE_ITEMS>
    </INVOICE>
</INVOICES>
```

And if possible remove ITEM_INVOICE_NUMBER element from final xml.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What is your specific question? -- P.S. Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't matter if XSLT 1 or 2 (I prefer simpler solution so if it is simpler in 2.0, why not to use it). If above is possible how to do that? How to map 2 xml files and produce one output xml from them (I didn't use xslt ever before).

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0? Do you know how to initiate an XSLT transformation and how to pass a parameter to the stylesheet? -- P.S. This is not the place to conduct a tutorial; you need to have a minimum grasp of the basic concepts before asking a question.

Comment: Ok basically, I would do all from java application. So where to start?

Comment: with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681037/execute-xslt-transform-from-java-with-parameter) I know how to pass parameters and how to invoke transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **very basic** stylesheet should give you a clue on how to proceed. It will be applied to the first XML you provided us in  input, and it assumes that the second XML storing additional information is named *data.xml*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:variable name="invoiceitems" select="document('data.xml')" />

    <!-- just copy the element, and process contents. Warning: attributes (if any) won't be processed. -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="INVOICE">
        <xsl:variable name="current.invoice.number" select="INVOICE_NUMBER" />
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            <!-- create an INVOICE_ITEMS element, and start to retrieve information from the other XML -->
            <INVOICE_ITEMS>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$invoiceitems//INVOICE_ITEM[ITEM_INVOICE_NUMBER/text() = $current.invoice.number]"></xsl:apply-templates>
            </INVOICE_ITEMS>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: great thank you. Just one more question, is there some option in xslt how to delete tag ITEM_INVOICE_NUMBER after processing?

Comment: You can do it during processing. I see a simple way to do it : add the following template in your stylesheet `<xsl:template match="ITEM_INVOICE_NUMBER" />`. This template does nothing, so that the *ITEM_INVOICE_NUMBER* won't be copied in the output.